# How to keep system tray icon with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, system-tray

I'm trying to create a code for a fan controller and I already got to the point of creating a system tray icon when closed, but when you click the icon to show the app and close again, the system tray icon no longer appears, can someone help me? Here's the part of the code responsible for the system tray icon:

```
from pystray import MenuItem as item
import pystray
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def quit_window(icon, item):
    icon.stop()
    root.destroy()
def show_window(icon, item):
    icon.stop()
    root.after(0,root.deiconify())
def hide_window():
    root.withdraw()
    image=Image.open("../Resources/icon.png")
    menu=(item('Quit', quit_window), item('Show', show_window))
    icon=pystray.Icon("name", image, "My System Tray Icon", menu)
    icon.run()

    root = tk.Tk()
    img = tk.Image("photo", file='../Resources/icon.png')
    root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', hide_window)
```

Comment: you have wrong indentations. And code with wrong indentations is useless. Edit question and crrect code

Comment: did you run in console to see if get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`. Maybe it runs in different way then you expect.

Comment: what does : root.destroy() do in your code ?